# <button> inside <a> not working in SharePoint page

Tags: html, redirect, button, sharepoint

I need to create an image slider which shows the image sliding one by one. I have a SharePoint page where the slider is implemented. I have used **Amazing Slider** While generating the Read More button. The HTML which is being generated for button is like below:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><button class="as-btn-blue-medium">Read  more...</button></a>
```

The button is generated perfectly, but when I click on it is refreshing the page not redirecting me to the *http://www.google.com*. However this is occurred in SharePoint page only, when I create simple `.html` file then  it is working perfectly.

What I need to do to make this working on SharePoint page?

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid html to have `<button>` inside of an `<a>`.  See the list of allowed elements for nesting [here](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element). For maximum compatibility with sharepoint you'll probably want to do something like:

```
<button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" class="as-btn-blue-medium">Read  more...</button>
```

Comment: Hello sir, actually the format of HTML is provided by Amazing Slider, if I change anything in HTML structure it messes up the design.